# Populate wx.MenuItem from a dictionary and Bind all MenuItems to the same Method (passing a dictionary value)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, variables, wxpython

Using Python 3.x and wxPython.

I'm working on a GUI tool that will likely need to be expanded and updated over time and I'm trying to reduce the amount of work (long term) as features are added.

I have a method that needs a variable passed to it, and then the method checks the dictionary to see which "ID" is associated with it, then uses that ID to trigger some automation.

```
job_dictionary = {
    'job_name_in_english': 'id_goes_here',
    'job_name_in_english': 'id_goes_here'
}
```

I have a very simple window setup and I'm populating a file menu with the following:

```
for key in job_dictionary:
    newitem = wx.MenuItem(file_menu,wx.ID_NEW, text = key,kind = wx.ITEM_NORMAL)
    file_menu.Append(newitem)
```

Then later on I want to bind them to a method, and pass that method the 'key' value, depending on which item they select from the menu.

Which is where I'm running into some difficulties. I was wondering if there was a way to bind them dynamically based on the key value within the dictionary, because once I've got that part done I can just do call the method and pass it the key:

```
def job_trigger(key)
    id = job_dictionary[key]
    #Rest Of Code...
```

Hopefully what I'm trying to do makes sense. I'm still new to building GUI applications, and this is the first time I'm dealing with a File Menu, and the first time I'm trying to implement something like this.

I know in a batch script I can do something like this:

```
set x=0
loop of some kind here(
set /A "x=x+1"
set menuItem%x%=foobar
)
```

Which would make the variable name dynamic, and then I was thinking I could bind them as they're being written. So I guess something like:

```
x = 0
for key in dictionary
     x += 1
     menu_item = 'menu_item_' + x
     'menu_item_' + x = wx.Menu().Append(wx.ID_FILEDLGG, key)
     'menu_item_' + x.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.job_trigger(key), key)
```

I know that's not the correct syntax for something like this, and I have no idea if that would be the appropriate way of handling this scenario, or if there is something else entirely I should be attempting.

Comment: How do you plan to implement that final functions? Will you write them, create class that handles them, or something different? You can also bind functions directly into dict so that is returns function.

Comment: The functions are already written, ultimately it's using the Operations Orchestration API to trigger job flows. It's a pretty simple function actually, all it needs is a job id and it triggers the job, then monitors the status, it doesn't return any values, just updates the status bar with the current status of the job running.

Comment: These types of automated shortcuts aimed at simplicity, seem like a good idea at the time but they rarely work long term. If you will be responsible for updates for the life of the project, it may be fine. However, if others have to maintain/update it, that may well not be the case. You also have to assume that your method of simplification is adaptable to be able to deal with all future requirements. It may seem like a pain, but if others have to maintain this in the future, explicit coding is better than implicit. Just an opinion but based on experience. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mistakenly confused the File menu with the dropdown menu. So here is my solution.

```
job_dictionary = {
    'job_name1': 'job_id_1',
    'job_name2': 'job_id_2'
}
```

Code to make Window and Panel goes here

```
#Create Dropdown Menu
jobs = list()
for i in job_dictionary.keys():
    jobs.append(i)
self.choice = wx.Choice(panel, pos=(5,5), size=(375,50), choices = jobs)
#Create Buttons
trigger_job_btn = wx.Button(panel, label='Trigger Job', pos=(290,50))
#Button Trigger
trigger_job_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.execute_job)
```

The above creates a list from the dictionary, then uses that list to populate the dropdown menu (wx.Choice). Then I create a button, and bind that button to a method.

Then the method looks like this:

```
def execute_job(self, evt):
        choice = self.choice.GetSelection()
        if choice == -1:
            wx.MessageBox('Please Make a Selection from the DropDown.',
                          'Warning', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        else:
            key = self.choice.GetString(choice)
            jobTrigger(key, job_dictionary[key])
```

The above method gets choice number, if it's blank, you get an error message popup informing you to make a selection. If it's a populated choice, it will then look for the string within that choice, and pass that to another method as the dictionary key value.

Answer (score 0):

From what I deducted, you might need only simple iteration over dict:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

a_dict = {
    "key_0": "value_0",
    "key_1": "value_1"
}

for i, v in enumerate(a_dict):
    print("current index: {}".format(i))
    print("current value: {}".format(v))

    # string manipulation
    builder_string = "prefix_" + str(i)
    print(builder_string)

    # rest of code...
```

If you also need keys, then you can use  `for key, value in a_dict.items():` and set index outside loop and increment it manually.

Comment: On the string manipulation, doesn't that just set it to (in your example) "prefix_key_0" but retaining the name of "builder_string"? What I'm trying to do is bind the items in the File menu to the same method, passing a different key to the method for each item listed within the File menu.

Comment: That's where I don't really understand the "environment". From where do you get method, and what exactly are your keys(dictionary)? Sorry for not understaning wx, I'm more used to Tkinter for building GUI in python. Btw, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and try to make minimal working example.

Comment: I found a way to do it with a dropdown menu, I was trying to do it from a file menu, I think I had my words messed up when I was reading things. But I have figured it out and will post my answer here shortly.